# Searching with extra params failing when ordering by desc or by limit 30

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli, sql-order-by

I have finally decided to include a search parameter in one of my mysql requests. It works when the "order by desc" or "limit 30" does not exist at the end, like below:

```
$sql = 'SELECT blahblah, bla FROM databasename WHERE lat >= ? AND lat <= ? AND lon >= ? AND lon <= ?';
$params = array( $minlat, $maxlat, $minlon, $maxlon );
if ( isset( $_GET['sear'] ) ) {
    $sql .= "AND (searcher LIKE ?)";

    $params[] = '%'.$_GET['sear'].'%';  

}
```

However, it does not work when "order by desc" or "limit 30" is included like below:

```
$sql = 'SELECT blahblah, bla FROM databasename WHERE lat >= ? AND lat <= ? AND lon >= ? AND lon <= ? ORDER BY autoinc DESC LIMIT 30';
$params = array( $minlat, $maxlat, $minlon, $maxlon );
if ( isset( $_GET['sear'] ) ) {
    $sql .= "AND searcher LIKE ? ";

    $params[] = '%'.$_GET['sear'].'%';  


}
```

**How can I get it working with the "limit 30" or "order by desc"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses ***must*** come ***after*** all your WHERE criteria

```
$sql = 'SELECT blahblah, bla FROM databasename WHERE lat >= ? AND lat <= ? AND lon >= ? AND lon <= ? ';
$params = array( $minlat, $maxlat, $minlon, $maxlon );
if ( isset( $_GET['sear'] ) ) {
    $sql .= "AND searcher LIKE ? ";

    $params[] = '%'.$_GET['sear'].'%';  
}
$sql .= ' ORDER BY autoinc DESC LIMIT 30';
```